# Some more parameter integrals

Tags: integration, analysis, gamma-function

It seems that the following formulas hold :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2n}+1}} dx = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2n})\Gamma(\frac{2n+1}{2n})}{\sqrt\pi}$$  for any integer $n > 1$

and

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^n+1}} dx = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n-2}{2n})\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{n})}{\sqrt\pi}$$ for any odd integer $n > 1$

Has anyone an idea how to proof this ?

Perhaps, some substitution removes the square-root, but I do not know which.

Comment: MathJax hint: $\text{\infty} = \infty$ ;-)
As to the substitution I thought about induction and $x=\cosh(u)$ for $n=1$

Comment: I just don't have an Idea for the induction step^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting $x^p=t$, the integral becomes
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^p+1}}\textrm{d}x=\frac{1}{p}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{\frac{1}{p}-1}}{(1+t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\textrm{d}t=\frac{1}{p}B\left(\frac{1}{p},\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{p}\right)=\frac{1}{p\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{p}\right)
$$
where we use the beta function as $B\left(r,s\right)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{r-1}}{(1+t)^{r+s}} dt$ (see http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12#E3).

Comment: Now use $\dfrac1p\cdot \Gamma\left(\dfrac1p\right) = \Gamma\left(1 + \dfrac1p\right)$ and you have it in the form of the OP.

Comment: Perhaps the real question would be how one arrives at the alternate Beta-function expression or identity. If you could maybe show how that is done, that would be lovely.

Comment: Performing the change $y=\frac{1}{1+t}$ you obtain the beta function in the standard form.